# std::cerr doesn't wait for std::cout (when running CTest)

Tags: c++, output, io-redirection, ctest

### The context

I wrote a logger printing messages for the user. Messages with level "debug", "info" or "warning" are printed in `std::cout` and messages with level "error" or "system_error" are printed in `std::cerr`. My program is not multi-threaded. I work under Linux openSUSE 12.3 with gcc 4.7.2 and CMake 3.1.0.

### My problem

I discovered that sometimes, when an error message (printed in `std::cerr`) follows a long information message (printed in `std::cout`) and when the output is redirected to the file `LastTest.log` by CTest, the error message appears in the information message (look at the example below). I don't well understand this behaviour but I suppose a writing thread is launched for `std::cout`, then the code continues and another writing thread is lauched for `std::cerr` without waiting the first one is terminated.

**Is it possible to avoid that without using only `std::cout` ?**

I don't have the problem in the terminal. It only happens when CTest redirect the output to the `LastTest.log` file.

*Note that my buffer is flushed. It's not a problem of `std::endl` coming after the call to `std::cerr` !*

### Example

#### Expected behaviour :

```
[ 12:06:51.497   TRACE ] Start test
[ 12:06:52.837 WARNING ] This
                         is
                         a
                         very
                         long
                         warning
                         message...
[ 12:06:52.837   ERROR ] AT LINE 49 : 7
[ 12:06:52.841   ERROR ] AT LINE 71 : 506
[ 12:06:52.841   TRACE ] End of test
```

#### What happens :

```
[ 12:06:51.497   TRACE ] Start test
[ 12:06:52.837 WARNING ] This
                         is
                         a
                         very
                         long
[ 12:06:52.837   ERROR ] AT LINE 49 : 7
                         warning
                         message...
[ 12:06:52.841   ERROR ] AT LINE 71 : 506
[ 12:06:52.841   TRACE ] End of test
```

### How I call my logger

Here is an example of how I call `std::cout` or `std::cerr` with my logger.
I call the logger with maccros like that :

```
#define LOG_DEBUG(X) {if(Log::debug_is_active()){std::ostringstream o;o<<X;Log::debug(o.str());}}
#define LOG_ERROR(X) {if(Log::error_is_active()){std::ostringstream o;o<<X;Log::error(o.str());}}
//...
LOG_DEBUG("This" << std::endl << "is" << std::endl << "a message");
LOG_ERROR("at line " << __LINE__ << " : " << err_id);
```

with

```
void Log::debug(const std::string& msg)
{
    Log::write_if_active(Log::DEBUG, msg);
}
void Log::error(const std::string& msg)
{
    Log::write_if_active(Log::ERROR, msg);
}
//...
void Log::write_if_active(unsigned short int state, const std::string& msg)
{
    Instant now;
    now.setCurrentTime();
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    for(std::size_t k = 0; k < msg.size();)
    {
        std::size_t next_endl = msg.find('\n', k);
        if(next_endl == std::string::npos)
            next_endl = msg.size();
        lines.push_back(msg.substr(k, next_endl - k));
        k = next_endl + 1;
    }
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(Log::mutex);
    for(unsigned long int i = 0; i < Log::chanels.size(); ++i)
        if(Log::chanels[i])
            if(Log::chanels[i]->flags & state)
                Log::chanels[i]->write(state, now, lines);
}
```

Here, the log chanel is the object dedicated to terminal output, the write function is :

```
void Log::StdOut::write(unsigned short int state, const Instant& t, const std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
    assert(lines.size() > 0 && "PRE: empty lines");
    std::string prefix =  "[ ";
    if(this->withDate || this->withTime)
    {
        std::string pattern = "";
        if(this->withDate)
            pattern += "%Y-%m-%d ";
        if(this->withTime)
            pattern += "%H:%M:%S.%Z ";
        prefix += t.toString(pattern);
    }
    std::ostream* out = 0;
    if(state == Log::TRACE)
    {
        prefix += "  TRACE";
        out = &std::cout;
    }
    else if(state == Log::DEBUG)
    {
        prefix += "  DEBUG";
        out = &std::cout;
    }
    else if(state == Log::INFO)
    {
        prefix += "   INFO";
        out = &std::cout;
    }
    else if(state == Log::WARNING)
    {
        prefix += "WARNING";
        out = &std::cout;
    }
    else if(state == Log::ERROR)
    {
        prefix += "  ERROR";
        out = &std::cerr;
    }
    else if(state == Log::SYS_ERROR)
    {
        prefix += "SYERROR";
        out = &std::cerr;
    }
    else
        assert(false && "PRE: Invalid Log state");
    prefix += " ] ";
    (*out) << prefix << lines[0] << "\n";
    prefix = std::string(prefix.size(), ' ');
    for(unsigned long int i = 1; i < lines.size(); ++i)
        (*out) << prefix << lines[i] << "\n";
    out->flush();
}
```

You can see that my buffer is flushed when the log instruction is executed.

Comment: Yes, but the C++ instruction printing the error message in `std::cerr` come after the instruction printing the last `std::endl` in `std::cout`.

Comment: Does anything change if you issue `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` at the beginning of your program?

Comment: @Hurkyl: `sync_with_stdio` is completely a different thing.

Comment: @Nawaz: Probably. But hard-to-find bugs usually occur in places where you've convinced yourself there can't be a bug to find, and this is an easy thing to test. (also, it makes the statement "`cout` is buffered" actually correct; in the implementations I've seen, `cout` usually isn't buffered at all with synchronization on; buffering is delegated to the `stdio` library)

Comment: @Hurkyl: In that case, the bug would be in the library itself.

Comment: @caduchon please post your code, then we wouldn't all have to be guessing here

Comment: @Nawaz: Actually, my bet is currently on redirection in Linux doing something surprising, and the main point of my comment is to eliminate interactions between Linux and how the `stdio` library gets set up. (also... sometimes there really are bugs in the library)

Comment: I posted my code as an edit.

Comment: Can you show how you are having CTest redirect `cout` and `cerr` both to the file? Can you make the problem happen without using CTest?

Comment: CTest produces a log file with the std outputs of each executable test. I can't say more about that. I can't reproduce without CTest, even by calling the same test with `> Test.log 2>&1`.

Comment: So the problem is with CTest, and your title is misleading. I missed the two references to CTest completely on my first skim read, so it might be worth making them more prominent.

Comment: You're right. It wasn't clearly identified when I wrote my question. Correction done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Answering my own question**

Finally, it comes from a [bug in CMake](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15600).

CTest is not able to manage the order of the two buffers, and then doesn't care about the exact order of the output.

It will be resolved in CMake >= 3.4.

Answer (score 21):

I've seen this behavior before in a few forms. The central idea is to remember that `std::cout` and `std::cerr` write to two *completely separate* streams, so any time you see the output from both in the same place, it's because of some mechanism outside of your program that merges the two streams.

Sometimes, I see this simply due to a mistake, such as

```
myprogram > logfile &
tail -f logfile
```

which is watching the logfile as it's written, but forgot to redirect `stderr` to the logfile too, so writes to `stdout` go through at least two additional layers of buffering inside `tail` before getting displayed, but writes to `stderr` go directly to the tty, and so can get mixed in.

Other examples I've seen involve an external process merging streams. I don't know anything about `CTest` but maybe it's doing this. Such processes are under no obligation to sort lines by the exact time at which you originally wrote them to the stream, and probably don't have access to that information even if they wanted to!

---

You really only have two choices here:

- Write both logs to the same stream — e.g. use `std::clog` instead of `std::cout` or `std::cout` instead of `std::cerr`; or launch the program with `myprogram 2>&1` or similar
- Make sure the merging is done by a process that is actually aware of what it's merging, and takes care to do it appropriately. This works better if you're communicating by passing around packets containing logging events rather than writing the formatted log messages themselves.

Comment: Actually, I have no control on how CTest launch the executable and redirect the output. I will try with `std::clog`, I never used it, it could be a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a C++ expert, but this might help...

I believe that the issue you are seeing here, when redirecting to a file, is caused by the cstdio library trying to be smart.  My understanding is that on Linux, the C++ iostreams ultimately send their output to the cstdio library.

At startup, the cstdio library detects if you are sending the output to a terminal or to a file.  If the output is going to the terminal then stdio is line buffered.  If output is going to a file then stdio becomes block buffered.

Output to stderr is never buffered, so will be sent immediately.

For solutions you could possibly try using `fflush` on stdout, or you could look into using the `setvbuf` function on stdout to force line buffered output (or even unbuffered output if you like).  Something like this should force stdout to be line buffered `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0)`.

Comment: FYI, `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` will turn off the behavior where operations on the standard streams (like `cout`) must behave as if you made the corresponding calls to the `stdio` library.